# How can I analyze the content of the cell in excel using php

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I want to analyze the data inside the cell. More specifically, divide it into house number street city.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from a `.csv` file you can use this example:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Also you can have a look to the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Then to get a particular parts of address, you can use this:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) you can get more information.

Comment: i posted a new question can you check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016113/how-to-compare-the-cell-in-excel-to-database-if-contains-the-word-using-php

Comment: what do you by the string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Comment: `substr()` method devides the string to a substring, in your case you can use it to extract words from sentences. If you are satisfied with my answer please mark it by clicking the grey check button below the downvote button.